# Ajax Chained Select Boxes Are Not refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ok so i have created a Javascript/PHP/Ajax application. I have a sequence of 6 select boxes. The first is hardcoded in HTML. When you change the selection it sends a variable via Ajax to PHP which uses the variable to query the database. When the second box changes it then sends the 2 variables from the previous select boxes.

Each time a select box is changes it adds another variable to send. In the end there is a total of 5 or 6 variables which is all good, everything is functioning well and almost doing what i want it to do.

My problems occur with select boxes 3 and 6.

Initially they work fine. But when you go back to change select box 2, number 3 does not refresh. The values stay the same as before. The same with number 6, when i change number 3, box 4 changes and in sequence box 5 changes, however box 6 remains the same as the previous query. All Ajax code used is identical with just variable names and relevant Elements changed.

Can anybody help? i will post the link to the application and the ajax code in question.

Just so you know only select box 1 is visible initially, the rest are generated by php/ajax onchange.

Heres the code in question

```
function getHTTPObject(){
 if (window.ActiveXObject) 
   return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
   return new XMLHttpRequest();
 else {
  alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
  return null;
 }
 }

function doWork(){ 
var selectBox = document.getElementById("SelectManufacturer"); // get  HTML select box by id
httpObject = getHTTPObject();

    httpObject.open("GET", "http://4udev.refixstudios.co.uk/wp-content/martTest/bNbAjax.php?inputText="
        +selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text , true);

    httpObject.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
            if (httpObject.readyState==4 && httpObject.status==200)
                    {
                    document.getElementById('selectModel').innerHTML =  httpObject.responseText;;
                    }
}
httpObject.send()
}


function networkSelector()
{ 
var selectBox2 = document.getElementById("SelectManufacturer"); // get  HTML select box by id
var selectModel = document.getElementById("modelSelector");
httpObject2 = getHTTPObject();

httpObject2.open("GET", "http://4udev.refixstudios.co.uk/wp-content/martTest/NetworkAjax.php?inputText2=" +selectBox2.options[selectBox2.selectedIndex].text +"&modelText2="+selectModel.options[selectModel.selectedIndex].text, true); 

    httpObject2.onreadystatechange = function()
{

if(httpObject2.readyState == 4 && httpObject2.status==200){


  document.getElementById("networkSelect").innerHTML = httpObject2.responseText;
}


}
httpObject2.send();
}

function minuteSelector(){ 
    var selectBox3 = document.getElementById("SelectManufacturer"); // get  HTML select box by id
    var selectModel3 = document.getElementById("modelSelector");
    var NetworkSelect3 = document.getElementById("networkSelector");

    httpObject3 = getHTTPObject();

    httpObject3.open("GET", "http://4udev.refixstudios.co.uk/wp-content/martTest/minuteAjax.php?inputText3="+selectBox3.options[selectBox3.selectedIndex].text+"&modelText3="+selectModel3.options[selectModel3.selectedIndex].text+"&networkText3="+NetworkSelect3.options[NetworkSelect3.selectedIndex].text, true);

    httpObject3.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(httpObject3.readyState == 4 && httpObject3.status==200){

    document.getElementById("minuteSelect").innerHTML =httpObject3.responseText;
}


}
httpObject3.send();
}

function textSelector(){ 
    var selectBox4 = document.getElementById("SelectManufacturer"); // get  HTML select box by id
    var selectModel4 = document.getElementById("modelSelector");
    var networkSelect4 = document.getElementById("networkSelector");
    var minuteSelect4 = document.getElementById("minutesSelector");

    httpObject4 = getHTTPObject();

    httpObject4.open("GET", "http://4udev.refixstudios.co.uk/wp-content/martTest/textAjax.php?inputText4=" +selectBox4.options[selectBox4.selectedIndex].text+"&modelText4="+selectModel4.options[selectModel4.selectedIndex].text+"&networkText4="+networkSelect4.options[networkSelect4.selectedIndex].text +"&minuteText4="+minuteSelect4.options[minuteSelect4.selectedIndex].text, true);

    httpObject4.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(httpObject4.readyState == 4 && httpObject4.status==200){

    document.getElementById("textSelect").innerHTML =httpObject4.responseText;
}


}
httpObject4.send();
}

function dataSelector(){ 
    var selectBox5 = document.getElementById("SelectManufacturer"); // get  HTML select box by id
    var selectModel5 = document.getElementById("modelSelector");
    var networkSelect5 = document.getElementById("networkSelector");
    var minuteSelect5 = document.getElementById("minutesSelector");
    var textsSelector5 = document.getElementById("textsSelector");

    httpObject5 = getHTTPObjectAgainB();

    httpObject5.open("GET", "http://4udev.refixstudios.co.uk/wp-content/martTest/dataAjax.php?inputText5="+selectBox5.options[selectBox5.selectedIndex].text+"&modelText5="+selectModel5.options[selectModel5.selectedIndex].text+"&networkText5="+networkSelect5.options[networkSelect5.selectedIndex].text +"&minuteText5="+minuteSelect5.options[minuteSelect5.selectedIndex].text+"&textText5="+textsSelector5.options[textsSelector5.selectedIndex].text, true);

    httpObject5.onreadystatechange = function (){

if(httpObject5.readyState == 4){

    document.getElementById("dataSelect").innerHTML = httpObject5.responseText;
}


}
httpObject5.send()
}
```

Here is the link to the application http://4udev.refixstudios.co.uk/csv-test/

The best way to test is buy selecting any manufacturer and model then network, after that select Apple---The New Ipad 4G, this is how you notice that it does not change. This selection should only bring back Orange as network

And Heres the PHP that it calls

```
<?php


if (isset($_GET['inputText2'])) 
{
    $manufacturer = ($_GET['inputText2']);

    if (isset ($_GET['modelText2']))
    {

        $model = ($_GET['modelText2']);



    }

}


$conA = mysql_connect("localhost","****","*****");
if (!$conA)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("refixstu_4udev", $conA);
$selectApplea = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_apple WHERE model = '$model' ");
$selectBlackberry = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_blackberry    WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectDoro = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_doro WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectHTC = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_htc WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectLG = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_lg WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectMotorola = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_motorola WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectNokia = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_nokia WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectSamsung = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_samsung WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectSony = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_sony WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectSonyE = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_sonyericsson WHERE model = '$model'");
$selectZte = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT network FROM wp_selector_ZTE WHERE model = '$model'");

?>

<select id="networkSelector" style="width:100px;" align="right"  onchange="minuteSelector()"> 
<option> Select Network </option>
<?php

                        // Start Apple Testing

                        if($manufacturer == "Apple")
                        {

                                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectApplea))

                                    { 
                                            foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }

                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "BlackBerry")
                        {                           
                            while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectBlackberry))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }
                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "Doro")
                        {                           
                            while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectDoro))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }
                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "HTC")
                        {                           
                            while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectHTC))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }
                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "LG")
                        {

                                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectLG))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }

                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "Motorola")
                        {

                                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectMotorola))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }

                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "Nokia")
                        {

                                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectNokia))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }

                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "Samsung")
                        {

                                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectSamsung))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }

                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "Sony")
                        {

                                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectSony))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }

                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "Sone Ericsson")
                        {

                                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectSonyE))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }

                        }
                        else if($manufacturer == "Zte")
                        {

                                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($selectLG))

                                    { 
                                        foreach(array_unique($rowa) as $model)
                                        {
                                            echo"<option>"; echo $rowa['network']; echo"</option>";

                                        }

                                    }

                        }


                        mysql_close($conA);
                        ?>


                        </select>
```

Comment: For half of the loops you use 'array_unique' but not for the rest. Without seeing the results of the queries its hard to tell if this matters or not.

Comment: i did not notice that, thanks for the comment i will amend those now. When you say results do you mean the output of the SQL?

Comment: yes. Without knowing more about what PHP is 'seeing' its hard to guess why you're seeing .. well.. what you're seeing...

Comment: k i will take you through each query with the variables that ajax sends.

Comment: 1st manufacturer is clicked. Example - Apple is passed to ajax. SQL - SELECT DISTINCT model FROM AppleTable; This populates the Model select box and echos it to the sceen. Next step. Model Select box onchange() - sends Apple and iPhone 4S 16GB as variables to Ajax. SQL - SELECT DISTICNT Network FROM AppleTable WHERE Model = 'iPhone 4S 16GB';This echos the list of DISTINCT networks (O2, Orange, T Mobile, Vodafone) to the select box. This patern of sending variables carries on through out the application. The model box always changes when new manufacturer is selected. Hope that helps

Comment: here is the program, if you test with Apple Ipad 4g first then refresh you will see what i mean http://4udev.refixstudios.co.uk/csv-test/

Comment: I have updated the code to show all functions in one file

Comment: I see what you mean. The next thing to check is the data. When you send the AJAX request have the PHP output it to the debugger - send it's output there too. Make sure that what you're querying is what you expect.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Strange isn't it. I have checked the error logs and found this

unexpected T_AS - This occurs in the php code above

Comment: Ok so the debugger is telling me object is not a function onchange

Comment: So i removed (this) from the onchange and now no erros output to debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the problem. My onchange called networkSelector(). I had a HTML form element named the same and that was conflicting. I have simple changed the function name and it works on my test server yay! thank you for the help. Muchly appreciated